# How to expires session automatically after 1 hour in nextjs auth?

Tags: next.js, next-auth

I am trying to expire the session automatically after 1 hour without success.

Currently, I am trying to set up a custom session.expires in session callback based on backend JWT token:

```
        async session({ session, token }) {
            const userId = token.sub

            const user = [...logic to populate the 'user' variable]

            session.accessToken = token.accessToken as string
            const payload: { exp: number } = jwt_decode(session.accessToken as string)

            session.user = user
            session.expires = new Date(payload.exp * 1000).toISOString()
            return session
        },
```

If I keep the browser window open after login, after 1 hour the user seems to disconnect because you can see that the object received from the endpoint "/api/auth/session" is empty, however, when reloading the page the session is repopulated with the expires property in the past.

```json
{
    "user":{},
    "expires":"2022-05-19T07:21:07.000Z",
    "accessToken":"ACCESS_TOKEN_GOES_HERE"}
```

PS: The "user" and "accessToken" properties are correctly populated. I omitted it for security reasons.

Comment: Have you tried setting the `maxAge` property in the [`session` option](https://next-auth.js.org/configuration/options#session) of the provider?

Comment: From NextJS Documentation: "Seconds - How long until an idle session expires and is no longer valid.". I don't want the session expires after 1 hour of user inactivity. I would the session expires after 1 hour no matter what happens.

Answer (score 0):

I've had the same requirement and I have been able to achieve this be setting a different key in the user object (since I also needed this in the user session) in the session instead of "expires" since nextAuth will automatically rotate the value of `expires` key when you refresh the page.

Set the session expiry value in the NextAuth `session` callback in the `[...nextauth].ts` file as below.

```
callbacks: {
  ....
  async session({ session, token }) {
    session.user = token.user;

    if (!session.user.session_expiry) {
      // set expiration to 12 hours for now
      const exp = new Date(new Date().getTime() + 12*60*60*1000).toISOString(); 
      session.user.session_expiry = exp;
    }

    return session;
  },
}
...
```

In your client code, you will need to check this expiry and call the signout method of nextAuth.

```
const { status, data: sessionData } = useSession();

const { user: { session_expiry: sessionExpiry = null } = {} } =
  sessionData || {};


useEffect(() => {
  const isSiteSessionExpired = sessionExpiry || new Date(sessionExpiry) < new Date();
  if (status === "authenticated" && isSiteSessionExpired) {
     signOut();
  }
}, [sessionExpiry, status]);
```

This should force the user to signout if the session has expired.

Bonus : If youre using typescript, use the below code to get type check for the session_expiry variable.

```
import { type DefaultSession } from "next-auth";

type UserWithSessionExpiry = {
  session_expiry?: string;
} & DefaultSession["user"];

declare module "next-auth" {
  interface Session {
    user: UserWithSessionExpiry;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I manage to get the expiration of the session, you need to use the session option in your handler like this

```
 session: {
   maxAge: 5
 },
 jwt: {
   maxAge: 5
 },
 callbacks: {
   async jwt({ token, user}) {
     return { ...token, ...user};
 },

   async session({ session, token}) {
     session.user = token as any;
     return session;
     }
 }
```

In this case I have to set the same time as my token generated in the backend, it could differ if the backend change the time and the front is not updated but I cannot find another way to keep those two sync

Hope this help you